# Python Pandas Column (stores set) Compare to Dictionary Set and Return Number

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, set

Have a list of over 15 MM records in a Pandas Data Frame, and am trying to determine number number of unique valid English words contained in that field.

How I can I speed this up?  The comparison.  I'm using set.intersect(..), but it is taking over an hour.  Code and Sample Data below.

```
df.info()
sys_id      float64
grp_id      float64
set_id      float64
desc        object
unique_set  object
```

They unique key for these record are the "*id" fields.
Desc is a User Defined Description

I create unique_set using the code below:

```
df['unique_set'] = df.data_desc.apply(lambda x: detSet(x))
```

Where detSet is defined:

```
def detSet(strDesc):
    if len(str(strDesc)) <= 1:
        # Return an empty set
        return set()
    else:
        # Remove all punctation
        strDesc = strDesc.translate(replace_punctuation).lower()
        # Remove all Non Alphabetic Characters (including Numbers)
        strDesc = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z ]', ' ', strDesc)
        # Remove all words less than 4 characters long
        strDesc = re.sub(r'\b\w{1,3}\b','', strDesc)
        # Remove all the extra spaces
        strDesc = ' '.join(strDesc.split())
        #
        return set(strDesc.split())
```

I then read a copy of the English Dictionary in from http://invpy.com/dictionary.txt

```
ENGLISH_WORDS = open('Dictionary.txt').read().splitlines()
ENGLISH_WORDS = [e.lower() for e in ENGLISH_WORDS]

df['num_english'] = df.unique_set.apply(lambda x: detNumEnglish(x)).astype(np.int16)

def detNumEnglish(setDesc):
    if len(setDesc) == 0:
        return -1
    else:
        return len(setDesc.intersection(ENGLISH_WORDS))
```

Some Sample Data:

```
141   9437  13522   {jelly, beans, pudding, cake, fruitc}
787   29575 5915    {ingerbread, sugar, plum, powder, jelly}
842   22909 28065   {pudding, bear, claw, sesame, snaps, m}
484   36065 25069   {isu, cake, candy, canes, ca}
897   54587 48574   {tart, fruitcake, dessert, bisc}
123   48335 36038   {chocolate, icing, marzipan, macaroon, apple}
293   36779 12239   {ars, sugar, plum, cupcake, danish, tiramis}
115   18478 43114   {e, pudding, gummies, chocola}
183   13346 33084   {roll, caramels, candy, fruitcak}
501   94397 47227   {cake, candy, canes, cake}
473   52269 44396   {e, gummi, bears, tiramisu, cake, candy}
```

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if this wouldn't be better on code review...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should create `ENGLISH_WORDS` as a `set` to speed up intersection and remove short words as they are filtered out of your other list:

```
ENGLISH_WORDS = {e.lower() for e in ENGLISH_WORDS if len(e)>3}
```

Then, seems that the `detSet` method is called a lot, and it does a lot of string manipulation, which is costly.

Let's take your original snippet:

```
def detSet(strDesc):
    ...
    else:
        # Remove all punctation
        strDesc = strDesc.translate(replace_punctuation).lower()
        # Remove all Non Alphabetic Characters (including Numbers)
        strDesc = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z ]', ' ', strDesc)
```

(That was your original code snippet)

Both lines above basically do the same thing. You'd just have to add the translation for the digits (and maybe other chars, to be refined) by doing:

```
replace_punctuation.update({i:' ' for i in range(ord('0'),ord('9'))})
```

when you create the `replace_punctuation` table. So you can drop the costly regex replace.

Once you've done that, you already have a string of space-separated words. You should split at this moment and filter out the small words. And the 3 following lines:

```
    # Remove all words less than 4 characters long
    strDesc = re.sub(r'\b\w{1,3}\b','', strDesc)
    # Remove all the extra spaces
    strDesc = ' '.join(strDesc.split())
    #
    return set(strDesc.split())
```

could be written directly as a set comprehension (1 or many spaces: doesn't matter if split is called without any argument) so you don't create temp lists (you create a lot of them in your code)

```
return {s for s in strDesc.split() if len(s) > 4}
```

This should be much faster since there's a lot less string and regex manipulation.

So to sum it up, here's how the sped up routine would look like:

```
def detSet(strDesc):
    if len(str(strDesc)) <= 1:
        # Return an empty set
        return set()
    else:
        # Remove all punctation & replace digits by spaces (using the new replace_punctuation table)
        strDesc = strDesc.translate(replace_punctuation).lower()
        # split, filter out small words, and create set comprehension directly
        return {s for s in strDesc.split() if len(s) > 4}
```

Aside `lambda` is overkill here:

```
df.data_desc.apply(lambda x: detSet(x))
```

could be simply (slightly faster too):

```
df.data_desc.apply(detSet)
```

(same goes for `df.unique_set.apply(lambda x: detNumEnglish(x))`)